# Assign fixed path to printer (/dev/usb/lp0)

Tags: usb, printing, udev

I have two USB printers. They are assigned a path depending on the order of turning them on. The first one is `/deb/usb/lp0` and the second one `/deb/usb/lp1`. However, I sometimes `echo` to these printers directly and need to know which one is lp0 and which one is lp1. Can I assign a fixed path in some way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write udev-rules to assign different names to the printer, depending on their serial numbers.

See http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-printer for an example of a udev printer rule.

Comment: please note that in Ubuntu (at least 10.04 and later) use `udevadm info` instead of udevinfo. So to check up on your lp0 printer you'd use the command `udevadm info --attribute-walk --name /dev/usb/lp0` (note that it generates tons of data)